# How to filter pandas dataframe by string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I have a dataframe with several columns. Here is an example:

```
A          B  C  D      MachineCall    F
0  1 2013-01-02  1  3   Machine1  foo
1  1 2013-01-02  1  3  Machine2  foo
2  1 2013-01-02  1  3   Machine3  foo
3  1 2013-01-02  1  3  Machine1  foo
```

I want to make a new dataframe that only uses data from rows with Machine1. I don't want to change the order of the columns.

I tried

```
df2 = df2[(df2 == 'Machine1')]
```

which got the error

`TypeError: Could not compare ['Machine1'] with block values:`

and

```
df2 = df2[(df2'MachineCall'].isin('Machine1')]
```

which got

`TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to Series.isin(), you passed a 'str'`

Comment: Shouldn't your title read 'filter' rather than 'sort'?

Comment: Yes, I can change that. Not sure if this question will still be helpful to others, though.

Comment: Regarding your errors the first one is probably because you're trying to compare a df containing mixed dtype columns with a str but this will barf when the dtypes don't match, for the second error it's pretty clear, it should be a list with a single element: `df2 = df2[(df2'MachineCall'].isin(['Machine1'])]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code works.

```python
df[df['MachineCall'].str.contains("Machine1")]
```

Answer (score 1):

`new_df = df2[df2['MachineCall'] == 'Machine1']`